# Vulkan coordinate system: is +Z inwards?

Tags: vulkan

According to this page:
https://matthewwellings.com/blog/the-new-vulkan-coordinate-system/

The Vulkan coordinate system has:

- The X axis increasing to the right
- The Y axis increasing downwards
- The Z axis increasing into the screen

In my own my own test, I can confirm the X and Y axis. However, for me, the -Z points into the screen, not +Z. By this, I mean:

- As X increases, the scene moves to the left, because the camera moves to the right.
- As Y increases, the scene moves up, because the camera moves downwards.
- As Z increases, the scene moves away, because the camera is moving backwards.

I believe the linked page over my own learning code, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this effect.

My scene consists of a single textured quad. This is the code that I'm using:

C++

```
// No rotation
auto identMat = glm::mat4(1.0f);
auto rotAmount = 0.0f;
auto rotAxis = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
mUBO.mModel = glm::rotate(identMat, rotAmount, rotAxis);

float eyeXPos = 0.0f;
float eyeYPos = 0.0f;
float eyeZPos = time * 1.0f;
auto eyePosition = glm::vec3(eyeXPos, eyeYPos, eyeZPos);
auto centerPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
auto upAxis = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
mUBO.mView = glm::lookAt(eyePosition, centerPosition, upAxis);

const float kWindowWidth  = 800;
const float kWindowHeight = 600;
auto verticalFOV = glm::radians(45.0f);
auto aspectRatio = kWindowWidth / kWindowHeight;
auto nearPlane = 0.1f;
auto farPlane = 100.0f;
mUBO.mProj = glm::perspective(verticalFOV, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane);
```

---

Vertex Shader

```
layout(location = 0) in vec2 inPosition;
// ...
gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
```

------------------------ EDIT ----------------------------------

I'm not losing sleep over this, or anything like that. But, since I decided to get myself a Vulkan t-shirt, I went ahead and created a test-case for this question, in case anyone is curious enough to run it. The function name that updates the UBO is called UpdateUniformBuffer(). The code is self contained, except that it needs the GLFW library. Also, it needs an up-to-date C++ compiler (I use VS2017).

t-shirt: https://teespring.com/vulkan#pid=2&cid=2397&sid=front

main.cpp
https://pastebin.com/RWpNDfjc

TestRenderer.hpp
https://pastebin.com/09TTF1e3

TestRenderer.cpp
https://pastebin.com/wCDV0CEk

shader.vert
https://pastebin.com/fb5f4hvF

shader.frag
https://pastebin.com/CCVpnmwj

Comment: It would seems so, but Vulkan doesn't impose any coordinate system on Your 3D scene (only on a framebuffer/image/window level). I'm pretty sure that with some kind of a (not so complicated) math-magic, by modifying projection matrices, rendering state etc. it is possible to inverse 3D coordinate system so right is left, up is down, near is far and vice versa.

Comment: @Ekzuzy: I understand that I can just multiply Z by -1 to get the effect as mentioned on the page that I linked. My question is more about why my code, as it currently stands, does not have that behavior by default (+Z into the screen).

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I know You can't use GLMs matrices directly because they are designed for OpenGL which requires depth data to be in the [-1; 1] range and Vulkan uses the [0; 1] range. Maybe this causes different behavior?

Comment: I am no expert in this and came here with the same question. I think the confusion comes from the fact that indeed vulkan (with default settings) has increasing z-values into the screen direction. It's the glm perspective matrix that reverses it. As far as I understand, this is on purpose, again to vaciliate better floating point precision where it's needed

Answer (score 2):

As you're using glm, just define `GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE`. It maps matrix depth ranges into Vulkans's [0..+1] range instead of OpenGL's [-1..+1] range.

Comment: yeah, I had that #defined, already. Doesn't change it. I removed it to see the effect, and it doesn't change it.

Comment: What version of glm are you using? In older releases this was called `GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE`.

Comment: 0.9.8.4 - It supports GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE, because I see it in the codebase.

Comment: GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE just changes the the clipping volume to span from 0 to 1. It doesn't reverse the z-direction. It seems to me that indeed glm perspective matrizes reverse the depth direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can pick your own depth test from [8 options](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#fragops-depth). So it doesn't matter which direction it goes as long as you clear the depth buffer to the correct value and use the correct depth test.

The biggest difference between opengl and vulkan is that NDC depth is from 0 to 1 rather than -1 to 1 it was in opengl. This helps avoid loss of precision when using floating point depth buffers.

Comment: Well, my question is about the camera moving through the 3D space, not about depth testing. I'm a noob, so perhaps I'm not understanding a deeper truth to what you're saying. In my mind, the stuff I'm talking about is unrelated to depth testing.

Answer (score 0):

I do realize this is 5 years old, and the OP may have figured this out by now, but for anyone else scratching their heads at this post, I have the solution.

The issue is not with the depth values of glm perspective matrix. Besides, the OP said that the `GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE` was already defined in OP's code. (I'm guessing in the OP's original code, because the code in the code links in the OP's **EDIT** section did not define `GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE` so I defined it in the example project below.)

The full example project with the fix that I came up with is here:
[https://github.com/Mausinator08/TestRenderer](https://github.com/Mausinator08/TestRenderer.git)

## The Issue

The real issue deals with the fact that the eye (camera) is always pointing at 0, 0, 0 while moving along the positive z axis and the eye (camera) starts at 0, 0, 0. So the camera immediately flips 180 degrees and since the texture is displayed on both sides, the texture is still rendered towards the camera and the camera "feels" like it is moving backwards along the -z axis. Reality is, it's still the +z axis, just the camera orientation is flipped.

## The Fix

In the example project I linked to above, I put comments in the TestRenderer.hpp file where the projection matrix, eye, lookat matrix, and etc are all being setup. I changed eyeZPos calculation from `float eyeZPos = time * 1.0f;` to `float eyeZPos = (time * 1.0f) - 10.0f;` to start the camera at the negative z axis 10 units away from the center where the quad is with the t-shirt texture. Sure enough, when running the program the camera gets closer to the t-shirt as expected, until it passes through the t-shirt and flips 180 degrees to continue looking at the center.